# Цвет текста в TextArea JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Можно ли в TextArea сделать цвет у части текста, например, чтобы какое-то повторяющееся слово было зелёного цвета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, но можно использовать [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX):

```
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea;

InlineCssTextArea area = new InlineCssTextArea();

// Поставить зелёный текст на четвёртой строчке
area.setStyle(4, "-fx-fill: green;");
```

А ещё лучше использовать [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) (доступен с javaFX 8):

```
Text text1 = new Text("Большой наклонный красный текст");
text1.setFill(Color.RED);
text1.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontPosture.ITALIC, 40));
Text text2 = new Text("Малый жирный синий текст");
text2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
text2.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 10));
//Соединение этих двух кусков
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(text1, text2);
```